# Where can I find "On the significance of the principle of excluded middle in mathematics, especially in function theory"?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm looking for L.E.J. Brouwer's article *"On the significance of the principle of excluded middle in mathematics, especially in function theory"*. I've searched my university catalogues and every open database I know of, but I can't find it anywhere. I'm not very experienced in looking up scientific publications, so I don't know what I can do now to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The article in its original language, German, can be found [here](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1925.issue-154/crll.1925.154.1/crll.1925.154.1.xml). I don't know where you would find an English translation.

For future reference, if you have access to it, [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/) (at the moment of writing the site is temporarily down) is where I first go to search for articles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you find this? Also, I'm Dutch, so although I'm far from fluent in German, I think I'll manage to struggle through it.

Comment: I searched for the author, found a search result where the title was in English. However, it said there that it was a Japanese translation of the German article. So I searched for articles written by Brouwer with the word "Dritten" in the title, and this came up.